# TypeScript function type compatibility

Tags: typescript, function, types

```js
var A: { [key: string]: string }
var B: { foo: string } = { foo: 'hahah' }

A = B // ok

var C: (state: { [key: string]: string; }) => void
var D = (state: { foo: string }) => {}

C = D // throw error
```

Cause `A = B` is ok, so I think `{ foo: string }` is compatible with `{ 
[key: string]: string }`

But `C = D` will throw an error that said `Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.Property 'foo' is missing in type '{ [key: string]: string; }' but required in type '{ foo: string; }'.`

Please tell me why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before we start, let's fix the return type of `C` - it should be `void` (instead of `{}`) because `D` doesn't return anything.

Now you get this error only with `--strictFunctionTypes` compiler option enabled.

Look at this in the following way:

Function `C` (in its parameter type declaration) states that it can handle objects with **any** keys.
Function `D` - requires the parameter to have at least `foo` key.

```
var C: (state: { [key: string]: string; }) => void
var D = (state: { foo: string }) => {
    console.log(state.foo.toUpperCase())
}

C = D // error with strictFunctionTypes

C({}) // will blow up at runtime
```

> Another way to describe the example is that the type `(x: T) => void` is bivariant (i.e. covariant or contravariant) for `T` in default type checking mode, but contravariant for `T` in strict function types mode.

More info [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strict-function-types)

Answer (score 1):

Because `A = B` doesn't mean `B = A`. :

```
var A: { [key: string]: string }
var B: { foo: string } = { foo: 'hahah' }

A = B // ok

var C: (state: { [key: string]: string; }) => {}
var D = (state: { foo: string }) => {}

C = D // throw error
// Because 
B = A // Error
```